# How to make Searchkick return what was passed on the search box plus what was chosen in the dropdown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

Can someone point me to the right direction on how to make `Searchkick` only return what was passed on the search box plus what was chosen in the category dropdown?

So here's how my current `Searchkick` feature works. I added `Searchkick` to my model `business.rb` and this belongs to the model `category.rb`.

I already implemented the basic usage of `Searchkick` which is to return what was passed on the search box e.g. I passed the address "Sample 123 St." and it will return all businesses of all categories with that address.

But now, I want to only return what was passed on the search box plus what was chosen on the category dropdown e.g. I passed the address "Sample 123 St." and chose "School" in the dropdown category and will only return "School" with that address.

Comment: How did you implement the basic feature of search, please share the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the category id in where conditions.

Like this

```
Business.search "search text", where: {category_id: YOUR_DROPDOWN_SELECTED_CATEGORYID}
```